# How can you check if there is an existing value in the array and not add it another time if so?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to push items to an array but I want that if there's a similar item in an array, to just update the count to 1 and not add the item another time on the array. I've tried plenty of things such as the `include()` function but it is not working as expected, because when I put `item.includes(product)` as I'm mapping through each product, whenever I add an item, the count gets updated for each product...

```
import React, {useState, useContext} from 'react'
import data from './data.js'
import useCountsContext from './context/useCountsContext.js'
var uniqid = require('uniqid');

function Shop({ data }) {
  const {count, setCount} = useContext(useCountsContext)
  const {item, setItem} = useContext(useCountsContext)

  const addCart = (productsId) => {
      setCount(count + 1)
      data.forEach((product) => {
       if (item.includes(product)) {
         product.count += 1
       }  else if (product.id === productsId) {
          setItem(item.concat(product))
        }
      })
  }
console.log(item)

    return (
        <div>
          <h1>Shop</h1>
          <div className="div___shop">
          {data.map(({id, img, button}) => (
            <>
              <img className="img___shop" key={id} src={img}></img>
              <div key={id}>
                <button onClick={() => addCart(id)}>{button}</button>
              </div>
            </>
          ))}
          </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Shop
```

my data file:

```
import diCaprio from './img/diCaprio.jpg'
import steveJobs from './img/steveJobs.jpg'
import lips from './img/lips.jpg'
import buda from './img/buda.jpg'
import spaceDog from './img/spaceDog.jpg'
import astroNube from './img/astroNube.jpg'
import banksy from './img/Banksy.jpg'
import banksyDJ from './img/banksyDJ.jpg'
var uniqid = require('uniqid');


const data = [{
  id: uniqid(),
  title: "Steve Jobs",
  img: steveJobs,
  homeImg: steveJobs,
  button: "add to cart",
  count: 0
},
{
  id: uniqid(),
  img: diCaprio,
  homeImg: diCaprio,
  button: "add to cart",
  count: 0
},
{
  id: uniqid(),
  img: lips,
  homeImg: lips,
  button: "add to cart",
  count: 0
},
{
  id: uniqid(),
  img: buda,
  homeImg: buda,
  button: "add to cart",
  count: 0
},
{
  id: uniqid(),
  img: spaceDog,
  button: "add to cart",
  count: 0
},
{
  id: uniqid(),
  img:astroNube,
  button: "add to cart",
  count: 0
},
{
  id: uniqid(),
  img: banksy,
  button: "add to cart",
  count: 0
},
{
  id: uniqid(),
  img:banksyDJ,
  button: "add to cart",
  count: 0
}
]

export default data;
```

Comment: Side note: you really shouldn't be mixing ES6 imports with `require()`. That'll only end up causing problems. Pick one, and stick to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`includes` will not work with objects. try `find` or `findIndex` instead.
Also I think your check is wrong. You need to check if `items` has the selected `productId` and if yes, then update its count.

```
 const addCart = (productsId) => {
      setCount(count + 1)
      data.forEach((product) => {
       let index = items.findIndex(itm => itm.id === product.id && productId === product.id)
       
       if (index >= 0) {
         let newProduct = { ...items[index] }
         newProduct.count += 1
         setItem( [...item, [index]: newProduct ])
       } else {
          setItem(item.concat(product))
        }
      })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since product is an object, `includes` will not work as it only do "shallow" comparison like if you have a simple array (i.e `['a', 'b', 'c'].includes('c');`

In your case you need to "find" the product by id to know if it exist.

```
 const addCart = (productsId) => {
      setCount(count + 1)
      data.forEach((product) => {

       const exist = item.find(i => i.id === product.id); // add this one

       if (exist) {
         product.count += 1
       }  else if (product.id === productsId) {
          setItem(item.concat(product))
        }
      })
  }
```

You can learn more about array.find [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).